# read complex file content to 2D array (matrix) C language

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

there is one txt file as followings:
how to separate the content and assign the value to different variables.

the row1: number means the size of the Matrix.
from row 2 onwards, it is the matrix.
But The code below has the issue with reading the file to the 2D array.
how to skip the first row to read the content to the 2D array correctly??

```
5
XXXOO
OXOOO
OOXXO
XXXXO
XOOXX

char Pattern[][5]
char filename[]
int size;
    FILE *fp;   
    fp = fopen("C://Users//user//Desktop//DATA.txt", "r");
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");  
      fscanf(fp,"%d", &size);
      printf("size is:%d\n", size);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)  
    {  
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)  
        {    
                fscanf(fp,"%c",&Pattern[i][j]);  // error
                printf("%c ", Pattern[i][j]);    // error
        }  
        fscanf(fp,"\n"); 
         printf("\n");   
    }  

    fclose(fp);
```

the print out reasult as follwoings:

```
size is:5
    X X X O 
O 
 O X O 
O O 
 O O 
X X O 
 X 
X X X O
```

Comment: This is not complex file...

Comment: Please describe what is not working. The "error" labels just mark lines which look like using an undefined/undeclared `Pattern`. But since we do not see all of your code, that might be irrelevant.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Your code is mostly lacking in the "verifiable" area, for not being compilable and a little "complete" for not even declaring `Pattern`.

Comment: To skip the first line, just `char buf[64]; fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)` after you open the file (and you only open it once, so decide which `fopen` you are using and delete the other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary approaches you can take (actually 3) reading information from a file. Either a *line-oriented* approach reading a line at a time into a buffer and then parsing what you need from the buffer, or a *character-oriented* approach where you read a character-at-a-time from the file and keep track of where you are by appropriately testing characters. (the 3rd approach is a *formatted-read* using the `scanf` family of functions, but there are pitfalls for the unwary).

In either case, since you don't know the number of rows and columns before hand, you will have to either declare your array as a VLA (*variable length array*, supported by C99 and later, and with earlier compilers by extension), or you will have to dynamically allocate storage after reading the number of rows and columns from line 1. Given the difficulty you are having with the read, we will stick to a VLA for storage.

Probably the easiest way to handle the read is using `fgets` with a fixed buffer and then parsing what you need from the buffer. Since your lines are 5-characters long (plus the newline, plus the nul-terminating character for a total of 7-chars), a fixed buffer of 64-bytes should be more than sufficient. (but don't skimp on buffer size, I'd rather allocate 10,000 bytes to many than 1-byte too few).

Putting together a short example using `fgets`, you could do something like the following that takes the filename to read as the 1st argument to your program (or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is given):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i, j, n = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {   /* read/validate 1st line */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no number on line 1.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* get num rows from 1st line */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: num rows not parsed from 1st line.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char array[n][n];   /* VLA for holding char (or allocate) */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* read each row into buf */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {       /* validate read */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: read failed at line %d\n", i+1);
            return 1;
        }
        if (strlen (buf) == MAXC - 1) { /* validate line fit in buf */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line %d too long.\n", i+1);
            return 1;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)             /* for each col */
            array[i][j] = buf[j];           /* assign char to array */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* output the contents of array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            putchar (array[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Your second option is a character oriented approach (with a `scanf` read of the 1st line to simplify conversion to `int`). After reading the integer from the 1st line, you must discard any remaining characters up to the `'\n'` to prepare to begin your read of characters on line-2. This method is actually a bit shorter because the validation is simpler as is discarding any remaining characters in each line after the 5 your are interested in, and there is no chance a line is too long to fit in your fixed size buffer.

A short example here could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c, i, j, n = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no number on line 1.\n");
        return 1;
    }   /* discard any remaining chars in line */
    for (c = fgetc(fp); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {}

    char array[n][n];   /* VLA for holding remaining chars */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* for each row */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)             /* for each col */
            if ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)     /* validate read of char */
                array[i][j] = c;            /* assign char to array */
            else {  /* if read failed before loops end -- error in file */
                fprintf (stderr, "error reading array[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
                return 1;
            }   /* discard any remaining chars in line */
        for (c = fgetc(fp); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {}
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* output the contents of array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            putchar (array[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A second alternative to the character oriented approach is to read all characters with a single read-loop rather than nesting loop for rows & columns. The is probably the simplest implementation of all. It is referred to as a state loop, where you read continually starting with the 2nd line and you keep track of the state of the rows and columns being filled with simple checks that will reset the state of the loop to begin reading the next row each time a newline is encountered. It also keeps track of whether the characters read in each line are within the first 5 you are concerned with and ignores all characters beyond that per-line (until the `'\n'` is encountered).

This method probably provides the greatest flexibility in all file parsing cases as you are simply reading each character until `EOF` is encountered and handling the data based on the state of the loop. A short example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c, i = 0, j = 0, n = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no number on line 1.\n");
        return 1;
    }   /* discard any remaining chars in line */
    for (c = fgetc(fp); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {}

    char array[n][n];   /* VLA for holding remaining chars */

    while (i < n && (c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) { /* fill n rows */
        if (c == '\n') {    /* if newline read, reset for next row */
            i++;            /* increment row count */
            if (j < n) {    /* check all cols full */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read %d cols.\n", n);
                return 1;
            }
            j = 0;          /* reset col count zero */
        }
        else if (j < n)     /* add 1st n chars per-row to array */
            array[i][j++] = c;
    }
    if (i < n) {    /* check all rows filled */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read %d lines.\n", n);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* output the contents of array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            putchar (array[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are literally dozens more approaches out there, but these should cover the most common.

**Example Use/Output**

In all cases, your output is the same:

```
$ ./bin/rdcomplexmtrx <dat/complexmtrx.txt
XXXOO
OXOOO
OOXXO
XXXXO
XOOXX
```

Look things over in all answers and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and information!

Comment: Sure, sometimes you just have to see it written a couple of different ways to help all the pieces of the puzzle fit in place. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

For filename, use a single `'/'` slash, or in Windows, use double `'\\'` slash:

```
fopen("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\DATA.txt", "r");
```

`fscanf(fp,"%d", &size)` will read the integer, but end of line character is will be read in the next read operation. Use `fscanf(fp,"%d\n", &size);` so that it reads end of line character.

Use `fgets` to read the whole line, including end of line. Example

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char pattern[5][5];

    int size = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &size);

    char buf[100];
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp))
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            pattern[i][j] = buf[j];
            printf("%c", pattern[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
        if(i == size)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the result I got by using your answer is as followings:????? 
X X X O O 
O X O O O 
O O X X O 
X X X X O

Comment: That's the way you are printing some output. I don't know what are the first characters which you are printing. The rest of it shows the characters in correct sequence.

Comment: Windows will use `fopen ("c:/users/user/desktop/data.txt", "r");` just as well.

Comment: it miss out the last row

Comment: It doesn't miss out anything. I just tested it with above full MVCE. You are doing something wrong.